# Manual Encryption

Tags: java, encryption

I want to send secure data(strings) from a client to a server. This is what i think i want to do:

- Turn the string into a byte array
- "scramble" the bytes by putting them out of order in a specific way
- Serialize array of bytes inside of a class
- send the Encrypted and Serialized class to the server

then the server would:

- Deserialize the class
- get the bytes for the string
- put the bytes in the right order
- make a string out of the bytes

would this be a good way to Manually Encrypt data? Is this secure? Is it even worth the time trying to make a manual encrypter?

Comment: If the client is going to be publicly available, no this won't be very good.  Someone could reverse engineer it.  If it's for a small group of people who have no interest or need, then it should be fine.  It'll stop anyone who has access to neither the server or client from decrypting the information.  If you want an example of when this fails, look at software validation and keygens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to roll your own symmetric encryption scheme, using a fixed key (the "specific way" you're scrambling the bytes) known to both sides. There's no advantage to doing this over simply using a build-in encryption scheme with a known key, and substantial potential disadvantages. It takes just a small implementation mistake to create an opening that malign users can exploit.

Unless you do encryption for a living, you can't do better than what's out there, known, and proven in the field ([AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is a good start). If security is important to you, don't try. If you want to experiment as a hobby, though, have fun.

Answer (score 2):

Would this be a way to encrypt the data?

If you're just "scrambling" the data, no. It would be "trivially possible" to reconstruct the plaintext if it's just being scrambled. (This means the first time someone wants to read the data, they probably will, but if they're not trying too hard, they won't stumble across it by accident.)

On the other hand, if you're then running a "real" encryption algorithm over it, the scrambling adds a negligible degree of difficulty to the decryption, but you're relying upon a simple scrambling being sufficient to slow down someone who's just cracked the "real" encryption, which seems unlikely to be worthwhile.

You'd probably do far better to stick with a well-tested encryption mechanism designed by someone who does math with very large prime numbers for a living. Java's encryption framework lets you fairly easily implement a public/private key system, or a double-blind key exchange system; for example, you can just use HTTP-SSL for data exchange without much set-up on your part.

Comment: PS: for more encryption options than Java's standard libraries provide, you might want to Google up “Bouncy Castle.” I haven't used it myself, but it seems to be well-regarded.

Answer (score 0):

No, jumbling is not very goood. For a simple scheme you can build on check out the XOR operator.

Comment: which, let it be noted, is also "trivial" to decrypt. It may take a certain length of intercept, but I wouldn't use this for anything more than "casually hiding" something from someone who isn't particularly likely to try to read it, e.g. the apocryphal "your mother" who doesn't poke around under the hood.